# WPF Page to Window Navigation

Tags: wpf

I have a **MainWindow** with **button 1**, when i press this button it navigate to  **Page1** placed inside a **Window1**. When i press **button 2** inside **Page1**, i need to close **Window1** and display **MainWindow**. Kindly help me to find a solution.

When i trying to access `MainWindow` object using :

```
Window1 w = Application.Current.MainWindow as Window1;
```

w is giving null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//display a new MainWindow
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Show();

//close Window1
Window1 w = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
w.Close();
```